# how to create 2 controllers with same actionresult 2 views but one implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got a controller in my mvc application like below.

```
public class BaseController: Controller
{
    protected void LogInfo()
    { 
        logger.InfoFormat("[SessionID: {0}, RemoteIP: {1}]", Session.SessionID,    Request.UserHostAddress); }
}

public class FirstController : BaseController
{

     public ActionResult Index(string name)
     {
        LogInfo();
        getQueryString();

        if(IsValidRec())
        {
            if(Errors()))
            {
               return View("Error");
            }

            var viewname = getViewName(name);
            return view(viewname);
        }
        else
            return view("NotFound"); 

     }
}
```

I need to create another controller(SecondController ) with same ActionResult method that FirstController has but without any implementation. Because I dont wont to repeat same code in 2 ActionResult methods.

what is the best way to do that. I tried in following way but I m getting error when I initialize my protected method 'LogInfo()'

```
public class SecondController : BaseController
{

     public ActionResult Index(string name)
     {
        var firstcontroller = new FirstController();
        return firstcontroller.Index(name); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you use routing to route both pages to the same controller?  Or is there some different logic in you second controller that needs to run?

Comment: no cant use routing, second one has to goto SecondConroller.

Comment: You mentioned you get an error with `LogInfo()` but you don't show us any code that shows that method, so we won't be able to tell you why you get an error with that method.

Comment: I Updated code for LogInfo method. I m getting null value for Session when I get request from SecondController.

Answer (score 1):

Put the part you want to re-use in the base controller

e.g.

```
public class BaseController: Controller
{
    protected void LogInfo()
    { ... }

    virtual public ActionResult Index(string name)
    {
        LogInfo();
        getQueryString();
        .....

        var viewname = getViewName(name);
        return view(viewname);
    }
}

public class FirstController : BaseController
{
    override public ActionResult Index(string name)
    {
            var result = base.Index(name);
            .... do more stuff ...
            return result;
    }
}

public class SecondController : BaseController
{
    // Don't need to override index if you 
    // want to do the same as in the base controller
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance like this (one way):

```
public abstract class MyControllerBase : Controller
{
  // whatever parameters
  protected SharedModel GetSharedModel()
  {
    // do logic
    // return model
  }
}

public class OneController : MyControllerBase
{
  protected ActionResult Index()
  {
    var model = this.GetSharedModel()

    return this.View(model);
  }
}

public class TwoController : MyControllerBase
{
  protected ActionResult Index()
  {
    var model = this.GetSharedModel()

    return this.View(model);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to put common functionality somewhere else in application and use that in both controller. Like we used to write helper classes or use shared services. It is not good to create the instance of controller and calling the Action method from that...from the Architectural point of view. If u still have doubt...please explain more about your common functionality...then I will be able to help more.

Comment: It has so many validations and based on those validation results I render different view(s).

Comment: This would make a good case for composition. You could write a class with a public method that takes various arguments and returns a View's name or location, for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to this type of issue: inheritance and composition.
In general, inheritance has less code, but is less flexible.

Here's a [more through discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).